# Device plays audio in background, Simulator does not

Tags: ios, ios6, avfoundation

Here's the issue:

- When running my app on a device, audio play in the background.
- When running my app on the simulator, the audio stop playing in background, and resumes when app is again in foreground.

I have done the following:

- `.plist` background mode is `audio`.
- I call code below in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
```

What am I missing?  I checked that `error` is `nil` after both methods.

Comment: Which version of iOS SDK on simulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm quite sure the simulator doesn't support background audio, unfortunately. You'll have to resort to testing on real devices.